# ApplesScript, autopress space bar

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, applescript, script, spaces

I am trying to run a script that will double press space bar in a fast sequence after this command

```
repeat 10000 times
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "g" using command down
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "g" using command down
    delay 2
end repeat
```

but whenever I try to do another script that includes space bar I get an error saying that spacebar wasn't defined

```
repeat 10000 times
    application "System Events" to keystroke space
    delay 0.5
end repeat
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the same script in parallel? It’s a bit unclear what “ whenever I try to do another script ” is. Would you mind editing your post to list in which order and timing you execute which scripts?

Comment: It's not `spacebar`, it's just `space`, e.g. `keystroke space` Also, you do not need to use `tell application "System Events"` twice, just put the `keystroke` _commands_ after it with an `end tell` to close the _block_.

Comment: @bmike here you go

Comment: @user3439894 cant seem to get it to work

Comment: Excellent. I’ve got to ask, what’s the end goal here? You might need an arduino to emulate the keyboard as AppleScript is rate limited by design. Something that knows USB can operate as fast as the bus clears the last key press.

Comment: @bmike I'm trying to run a script for this game I play where you press g to charge mana and press space to train a certain skill but it requires you to complete such task 1k times before you can max out the skill, and I don't really wanna put in the effort of doing it my self, so if I could get it to both hold g for a certain amount of time and then press the space bar twice right after in sort of a 0.5 sec time period in between the space bar presses it would really help.

Comment: You could try `key code 20` although that may not work either. BTW The target of the keyboard activity needs to have focus, so are you activating the target app first?

Comment: @user3439894 what do you mean?

Comment: You could try `tell application "System Events" to key code 20` instead of `tell application "System Events" keystroke space` -- To the second point. Any `keystroke/key code` that **System Events** processes has to go somewhere and in your case to the game. It it doesn't have focus it doesn't receive the `keystroke/key code`, so are you activating the target app prior, e.g. `tell application "AppName" to activate` and then an appropriate `delay` before `tell application "System Events" ...` ?

Comment: @user3439894 so could you give me an example of what it would look like? Ah, I see so first activate the app, for example with a 3-second delay and then tell application System Events to keycode 20? And then add a delay to the repetition of space key presses? Also, key code 20 seems to be the number 3, so I changed it to keycode 49. Well I did get it to work but then it no longer works, this is what I came up with ` ` `repeat 10000 times
 tell application "Roblox" to activate
 delay 3